# View notes for certain package in ArchLinux without package removal?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I've installed couple of packages and forget what they recommended. Now i want to view their notes, recommendations. Only way i know how to do this is remove it and install it again:

```
# pacman -Rdd <package>
# pacman -S <package>
```

I'd like to find direct way to see notes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the packages can be viewed online in the [Arch Package Database](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/). Once you have located your package, simply view it in [svntogit](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/).

If you use [surfraw](http://surfraw.alioth.debian.org/), there is even [an elvis](http://surfraw.alioth.debian.org/#elvilist) for the package database...

Another alternative to [Chris' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39534/6761) is, if you have [ABS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ABS) installed, is just to read the PKGBUILD or $pkg-install file from your `/var`:

For example, if you wanted to read the `mplayer` files, you could just:

```
vim /var/abs/extra/mplayer/PKGBUILD
```

<sup>*Note:* running Arch without using ABS is like swimming fully clothed; you can do it, it's just not as much fun...</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The notes you see are part of the PKGBUILD and/or installation script, you can get it without having to reinstall.

Firstly, download the package tarball (`fakeroot pacman -b . -Syy && fakeroot pacman -b . --cachedir . -Sw package`, or if you don't care about being root, `pacman -Sw package`) and extract it (`tar xvzf package-*.tar.gz`). Then you may view the `PKGBUILD` and `.install` files (if any), these will contain the information that you are looking for, and more.